# Make equality operators return binary instead of bool

Tags: c++, boolean, bit-manipulation, equality

Is there any way to make equality operators (`!=`, `==`) return in binary `int` rather than `bool`?

That is,

`4 != 4`

returns `(bool) false`, but I'd like to receive `(int) 0`.

The easiest way is to do a cast:

`int(4 != 4)`,

but will this always work in general on all systems, independent of how they represent boolean quantities?

Comment: You can only overload operators for user-defined types. (not with `int`)

Comment: I'm more so asking about the portability of casting a bool to an int

Comment: It will always work IIRC, I think there is a dupe.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate then, thanks